# Strange \patchcmd behavior

Tags: etoolbox

I have a question about a strange behavior of the etoolbox package. Roughly speaking, I want to define a command for defining macros so that the user says `\mynewcommand\acommand{some code}` and it will define `\acommand` to do some setup stuff, run `some code` then do some cleanup. I want to use `\patchcmd` to turn any occurrences of `\options` in `some code` into an argument (say #1). However, I run into some difficulties with `\patchcmd` saying `macro cannot be retokenized cleanly` due to some strange difficulty with spaces.

One solution to this problem is to disable the `etoolbox` scan safety check by saying `\def\etb@ifscanable##1{\@firstoftwo}`. I don't really like this solution because it reaches into the `etoolbox` package.

If I could understand what is happening in the following example, I think I would be able to fix my definition without doing this. So are there any `etoolbox` experts out there who can tell me why the following code behaves the way it does?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\tracingpatches
\makeatletter
\begin{document}

% Breaks sometimes:
\def\mynewcmda#1#2{
    \gdef#1{%
        \acommand
        #2%
        \options
    }
    \patchcmd#1{\options}{\athing}
        {\message{replacement worked}}
        {\message{replacement failed}}
}

% Always works:
\def\mynewcmdb#1#2{
    \gdef#1{%
        \acommand
        #2%
        \options
    }
    \bgroup
    % Skip retokenization check, so "++ macro can be retokenized cleanly":
    \def\etb@ifscanable##1{\@firstoftwo}
    \patchcmd#1{\options}{\athing}
        {\message{replacement worked}}
        {\message{replacement failed}}
    \global\let#1#1
    \egroup
}

% Always works:
\def\mynewcmdc#1#2{
    \gdef#1{%
        \acommand{}%
        #2%
        \options
    }
    \patchcmd#1{\options}{\athing}
        {\message{replacement worked}}
        {\message{replacement failed}}
}

% Doesn't work for some mysterious reason
\mynewcmda\testa{
    do things
}
% All the rest of these work:
\mynewcmda\testaprime{%
    do things
}
\mynewcmdb\testb{
    do things
}
\mynewcmdc\testc{
    do things
}
\end{document}
```

The log file says:

```
[debug] tracing \patchcmd on input line 50
[debug] analyzing '\testa'
[debug] ++ control sequence is defined
[debug] ++ control sequence is a macro
[debug] -- macro cannot be retokenized cleanly
[debug] -> the macro may have been defined under a category
[debug]    code regime different from the current one
[debug] -> the replacement text may contain special control
[debug]    sequence tokens formed with \csname...\endcsname;
[debug] -> the replacement text may contain carriage return,
[debug]    newline, or similar characters
replacement failed
```

and then a bunch of messages saying the other `\patchcmd`s succeeded.

Comment: `\athing` could be directly given in the macro definition instead of the detour with `\options`? Also, it is on purpose that the macro is defined globally (`\gdef`), but redefined locally (`\patchcmd`)?

Comment: Can there be multiple occurrences of `\options` inside the second argument? Or at most one?

Comment: The following should always work: `\def\mynewcmd#1#2{\gdef#1{\acommand {\let\options\athing #2}\options}}`

Comment: @Werner Multiple occurrences of `\options` can happen, so I defined a helper command `\patchrepeat` which recursively applies `\patchcommand` until it fails. I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek In response to your first question, I actually have a reason to do it that way. To your second question, no it's not on purpose, I want the change to be global, that's why I say `\let#1#1` immediately afterwards. Is there a global version of `\patchcmd`?

Comment: @Hood: Why not use my suggested definition of `\mynewcmd`?

Comment: Rather `\global\let#1#1`.

Comment: Since `\patchcmd` does not work in all cases, it could be better to use some expansion trickery to replace `\options` during the definition, e.g. `\xdef#1{\unexpanded{\accomand{}#2}\unexpanded\expandafter{\options}}`

Comment: This feels like an 'x-y' question: can you explain the wider context and what actually needs to be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not at all strange. The problem is that a macro cannot be safely rebuilt if the string representation of its replacement text contains something like

```
\macro<space><space>
```

because this could refer either to `\macro` followed by a space or to `\macro<space>` (with a trailing space in its name).

Defining macros with a trailing space in their name is done all the time: each `\DeclareRobustCommand` makes one, for instance.

Disabling the check is quite risky, because you can end up with a macro doing very different things than expected.

Where does the bad space pop out from?

```
\mynewcmda\testa{
    do things
}
```

The end-of-line after `{` is the culprit.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I don't want to ask the user to put a `%` there, so I guess the best solution is to make sure I can put an extra pair of braces or something before the user code is dumped in so that the space isn't problematic.

Also, does this mean that if I ever use `\protected@edef` to define `\somemacro`, I should never expect `\patchcmd` to work on `\somemacro`?

Comment: Also, did you mean there to be only one space in `\macro<space><space>`?

Comment: @HoodChatham The detokenized version of `\macro` is the string `\macro<space>`